# Is there a way to launch the Facebook and Twitter app via a HTML page?

Tags: html

I am wondering if anyone will be able to help me and if they know how to launch the Facebook and Twitter apps via a HTML page? Is there a way this can be achieved? Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

so use fb:// instead of html:// .

For twitter it's twitter://